# Criptografia/Descriptografia Android

Tags: android

Alguém tem algum exemplo de Criptografia/Decriptografia no Android?

E que tenha uma segurança interessante?

Lembrando que utilizo no desenvolvimento para Android a linguagem Java.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Criptografia e De criptografia Android](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114617/criptografia-e-de-criptografia-android)

Comment: Você quer criptografar e descriptografar no próprio dispositivo, ou por exemplo criptograr no dispositivo e descriptografar no servidor, usando criptografia assimétrica?

Comment: O que você chama de segurança Interessante? Utilizar um algoritmo padrão NSA / RSA? Algoritmos proprietários com curva elíptica?